# VM Reference - Android NDK Testing with GoogleTest

Tags: android, android-ndk, jvm, dalvik, googletest

I am running tests for Android native code using googletest.

Googletest creates an executable that is run on the device. However, one of the dependencies requires a reference to the VM, which according to my understanding is not available in the test environment.

I would like to:

1. Confirm that there's no VM associated with running the executable and hence no way to get a reference to an object that does not exist.
2. Find out if I could run the executable from an Android application (perhaps using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()) and somehow pass a reference for the underlying VM.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: One way to get hold of the VM in a process when you have no other reference is with `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp633 .  If the executable isn't linked against the VM, then this symbol won't exist.

Comment: Yes, thank you. However, the Android jni.h excludes that method.

Comment: Excludes it how?  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/lollipop-release/include/nativehelper/jni.h

Comment: See line 1115 in jni.h here: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/prebuilts/ndk/7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h

Comment: How would I go about linking the VM against the executable? Is there any library in particular I should link to?

Comment: So if I use the header file that you provided in your link (or the one for the appropriate platform) that should be enough so that I can call JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs()?

Comment: Let me update that previous link I posted (see line 1133): http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/prebuilts/ndk/current/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h

Comment: So the jni.h that comes with NDK has those function declarations def'd out.

Comment: If the executable has a VM in it, you'll be able to find the function with dlsym().  I'm still unclear on what exactly you're trying to do.  Let me point out that a given process either has a VM in it or doesn't; if you were expecting to get a reference to some globally shared VM (perhaps equivalent in scope to the Linux kernel), there isn't one.  It's just a library of code (libdvm.so or the Art equivalent) linked into app_process that gets invoked or doesn't.

Comment: @fadden Thank you for your helpful answers... I managed to solve the issue I was working on... I will post more details later.